# How can the quality of a Video be set when using the Youtube Embedded Player from Code?

Tags: youtube

setPlayerQuality() doesnt seem to work. There must be a way, as when quality is manually set from the player control bar it works!
When using the webpage with the Youtube embedded player on a laptop atleast able to set manually with the help of the control bar, however on an android mobile the same page doesnt show the option to change quality on the control bar.

Need to set quality via code...please help!

Comment: Which tech are you using

Comment: used loadVideoById(videoId,0,quality) ...it did not work.

Comment: used event.target.setPlaybackQuality(quality) ... it did not work either

Comment: just using javascript on an html page and using Youtube iFrame APIs